# Can I call Knockout's ko.applyBindings with an element that has not yet been injected into the DOM?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

My question is pretty simple. Is the following code, which does seem to work just fine (click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/X8RVP/1/) to see a working fiddle), actually a valid use of ko.applyBindings or are there side effects and/or issues that could surface?

```
var viewModel = {
    sampleText: ko.observable('hello world!')
};

// this HTML would be loaded from the server
var htmlWithBindings = '<b data-bind="text: sampleText"></b>';
var jQueryObj = $(htmlWithBindings);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, jQueryObj.get(0));
$('#main').append(jQueryObj);
```

The benefit with this approach is that you can apply all the bindings to the HTML **before** you actually add it to the DOM, so you don't get that effect where you see the empty HTML for a brief second before the bindings take effect. Any reason not to do this?

Comment: Looks like a smart way to do it! I wouldn't like to say whether their are any adverse reasons to do this... will be interesting to see what the experts say. I'm waiting for RP Niemeyer's thoughts! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is disposal logic in Knockout related to the computed observables used in bindings that will run when it believes that an element is no longer part of the DOM.  In your case, you may inadvertently hit this logic and bindings might be disposed.

Here is one example, where you bind an element to an observable, then that observable is updated as part of the `value` binding on a `select` element.  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/X8RVP/4/

After some further research, I don't think that your technique is necessarily going to fail in every scenario, but I would be aware of things like I listed above.

You could choose to hide the element while bindings are being applied or use named templates (in script tags) for major sections, so that the elements are not shown before they are being bound.

The named templates help in that you will never see your "templates" get rendered like you potentially can with using control-flow bindings (`if`, `with`, `foreach`) or even just normal elements with bindings.  It does not necessarily prevent the problem that you are trying to prevent, but it can definitely help as the bindings will happen right as the elements are added to the DOM.  Consider this one with named templates: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/X8RVP/5/ vs. this one without http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/X8RVP/6/.  Bindings are applied in a setTimeout to simulate some delay in the page loading and DOM being ready.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. You are probably correct that issues could arise using this approach, but the example fiddle you provided doesn't actually highlight the issue. The problem with your example was that you were only calling applyBindings on the first bold tag, so of course the second bold tag wasn't getting bound. If you wrapped a div around both bold tags like: [http://jsfiddle.net/X8RVP/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/X8RVP/3/), then the example works just fine. Also, can you elaborate on how the use of named templates would address the "empty HTML" issue? Thanks.

Comment: You are definitely right on the sample.  I should have taken a closer look.  I updated the response to show a breaking sample and to show what I had meant about named templates.